# Using Angular-UI-Bootstrap. How do I get only the CSS from bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs

I want to use bootstrap in my angular project, and I'm looking at http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/getting_started but it says one of the requirements is the bootstrap CSS.

How can I install only the CSS?  What is the best way to do that?  I have installed angular, angular-animate, and angular-bootstrap using bower.  Just need to install the css.

Here's how I'll use it, please let me know if its correct -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      ....
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/: *bower install bootstrap*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [Bootstrap's Get Started Page](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/). They give you several different options. Here's their CDN:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And Bower

```
$ bower install bootstrap
```

After you have your source just `<link>` to it within your `<head>`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS Bower *check folder for correct file name -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      ....
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks!  i used this to test first, and then i used bower to install it into my project.  thank you

Comment: Great. glad to hear it worked out. Go ahead and mark it as correct to help out others with the same question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is absolutely correct. You just need to download bootstrap from there website . that will have both CSS nd JavaScript. You should just add the CSS in your head tag

You can also install it through bower

```
Bower install bootstrap
```

After this check the bower_components folder to find bootstrap